# Wordpress plugin not rendering react component

Tags: reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-plugin-creation

I was trying to learn some wordpress react plugin development. Found this simple plugin [here](https://github.com/LearnWebCode/brads-boilerplate-wordpress/tree/main/brads-boilerplate-block-plugin-tailwind)
But its not rendering the react frontend on pages.

if I change `'render_callback' => array($this, 'renderCallback'),` to `'render_callback' => array($this, 'renderCallbackBasic'),` in [here](https://github.com/LearnWebCode/brads-boilerplate-wordpress/blob/f816c44ad60cbd944d7f0fd0b8635c9582dee9af/brads-boilerplate-block-plugin-tailwind/index.php#L22) it show the basic rendering, but something is blocking from react component rendering.

Any idea?

Comment: any error on console?

Comment: Nothing in console. It looks like the react component never got invoked.  But no idea why.